# Getting 404 error while running Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, model-view-controller

I am getting 404 error, while running spring mvc project.
I have mapped root request to my home.jsp and I am using spring java annotation configuration.
checked my mapping it looks fine for me. please help me to solve the issue I am not able find where it goes wrong.

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKEuy.png)

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home()
    {
        System.out.println("jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Dispatcher Servlet Config

```
public class DispServler extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[] {ConfigurationClass.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.veera")
public class ConfigurationClass {
    
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver vr = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        vr.setPrefix("/");
        vr.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return vr;
    }

}
```

Project structure

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsLyJ.png)

I have added System.out.println() statement inside my mapping method
but it is not printing my that statement in console also.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home()
    {
        System.out.println("jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3ij4.png)

Answer (score -1):

I guess, you are trying to access incorrect endpoint in browser, although you specified here root mapping, so, try to access **localhost:8080/** or if you want to change home JSP to map to **/Practice** endpoint, change next code to next:
This:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home()
    {
        System.out.println("jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

To this:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/Practice") // this line
    public String home()
    {
        System.out.println("jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

This is because **@GetMapping** annotation maps your JSP page to **localhost:8080/Practice** now